# Prism in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a prism using `plot_surface`
I have `point`- vertices `faces` and `edges` I have all the data to build, but there is no understanding of how to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
point=np.array([[0,0,1.322876],[1.309307,0,0.1889822],[-0.9819805,0.8660254,0.1889822],[0.1636634,-1.299038,0.1889822],[0.3273268,0.8660254,-0.9449112],[-0.8183171,-0.4330127,-0.9449112]])
faces=np.array([[0,3,1],[2,4,5],[0,1,4,2],[0,2,5,3],[1,3,5,4]])
edges=np.array([[2,4],[1,4],[3,5],[0,2],[2,5],[1,3],[0,1],[0,3],[4,5]])
x=np.array(point[:, 0])
y=np.array(point[:, 1])
z=np.array(point[:, 2])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.scatter(x,y,z,depthshade=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I would be grateful for any answer

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Your text has no idea, followed by a blob of code that does what you seem to have no idea about. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think op tries to plot the polygon mesh in the figure he uploaded. The code he attached is what he tried so far which plots the vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried my best with the color

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

point=np.array([[0,0,1.322876],[1.309307,0,0.1889822],[-0.9819805,0.8660254,0.1889822],[0.1636634,-1.299038,0.1889822],[0.3273268,0.8660254,-0.9449112],[-0.8183171,-0.4330127,-0.9449112]])
faces=np.array([[0,3,1],[2,4,5],[0,1,4,2],[0,2,5,3],[1,3,5,4]], dtype = 'O')
edges=np.array([[2,4],[1,4],[3,5],[0,2],[2,5],[1,3],[0,1],[0,3],[4,5]])
face3d = [[point[y] for y in x] for x in faces]
edge3d = [[point[y] for y in x] for x in edges]
x=np.array(point[:, 0])
y=np.array(point[:, 1])
z=np.array(point[:, 2])

ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='.')
for i, p in enumerate(face3d):
    if i!=1:
        ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([p], facecolors='red', alpha=0.5))
    else:
        pass
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(face3d[1], facecolors='yellow', alpha=0.5))
ax.add_collection3d(Line3DCollection(edge3d, colors='black', linewidths=1, linestyles='-'))
ax.view_init(-80, 40)
plt.show()
```

[image]